# Create a new column based on a specific value appearing in a row at least once from the specific columns using R?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have something like this

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5
  Y     Y   Y    N    N
  N     N   N    N    Y
  Y     Y   Y    N    N
  N     N   N    N    N
  N     Y   N    N    N
  N     N   N    N    N
  Y     Y   Y    Y    Y
```

Once i run the script i expect my result to be

```
   col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|result
  Y     Y   Y    N    N       Y
  N     N   N    N    Y       Y
  Y     Y   Y    N    N       Y
  N     N   N    N    N       N
  N     Y   N    N    N       Y
  N     N   N    N    N       N
  Y     Y   Y    Y    Y       Y
```

I tried something like this, but it did not work

```
COL_LIST <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")

df$result<- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(any(df[COL_LIST] == "Y"), "Y", "N"))
```

Comment: You can vectorize this with `c("N", "Y")[1+(rowSums(df[COL_LIST] == "Y") > 0)]`.  In your code, `ifelse(apply(df[COL_LIST] == 'Y', 1, any), "Y", "N")`  AFter you specified the lambda function `function(x)` `x` is the elements of the row.

Comment: Your attempt is so close! Just change `df[COL_LIST] == "Y"` to `x == "Y"` and it should work. When you have `function(x)` you should use `x` inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply`:

```
df$result <- apply(df, 1, function(x){ifelse("Y"%in%x, "Y", "N")})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized option with `rowSums`

```
df$result <- c("N", "Y")[1+(rowSums(df[COL_LIST] == "Y") > 0)]
```